# Store and access data files in lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda

How do I store custom file (.json in my case) in a lambda layer, so that I can access it like npm modules? I use node.js as a runtime. My current layer folder structure looks like this:

[image]

My modules stored in `node_modules` are visible and can be accessed as:

```
const { Client } = require('pg');
const knex = require('knex');
```

But when I try to list available files, I don't see my `service-account-file.json` file:

```
fs.readdir('./', (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    console.log('@file')
    console.log(file); // Returns only index.js
  });
});
```

Comment: why you want to store json file inside layer you can store in S3 bucket and access directly in lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to use stored data files in Lambda function. Create a folder with name `data_files`, put your `service-account-file.json` file in there.

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require("fs");

const loadDataFile = (file) => {
    
    //create the filename including path
    const fileName = `./data_files/${file}`;
    //set up the variable
    let resolved;
    //if we have a lambda environment then add that to the path to resolve
    if (process.env.LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT) {
        //this creates an absolute path
        resolved = path.resolve(process.env.LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT, fileName);
    } else {
        //otherwise resolve to the local path
        resolved = path.resolve(__dirname, fileName);
    }
    try {
        //get the text data as a string
        let data = fs.readFileSync(resolved, 'utf8');
        //convert to JS object
        let parsedData = JSON.parse(data);

        //TO DO - work data if required

        //then return the data 
        return parsedData;
    } catch (error) {
        //if there'a an error in the data fetch then we need a report
        console.log(error.message);
    }
};

const data = loadDataFile('service-account-file.json');
```